# How do I enable NTFS write support?

Tags: 11.10, ntfs

The NTFS Write capabilities were removed in Ubuntu 11.10.
Henceforth, I cannot write/delete on my External NTFS hard drive, neither can I on the NTFS partition hosting MS Windows.

I tried to install NTFS-config (and adding the command sudo mkdir -p /etc/hal/fdi/policy to make it work) but before installing it, it asks for removing these packages to resolve dependencies, so what the heck?
Is there any other way to write on NTFS partitions in Ubuntu 11.10? Which can be installed smoothly.

> ```
> Remove the following packages:                       
> 1)       flashplugin-downloader                             
> 2)       flashplugin-installer                              
> 3)       libasound2                                         
> 4)       libasound2-plugins                                 
> 5)       libasyncns0                                        
> 6)       libatk1.0-0                                        
> 7)       libaudio2                                          
> 8)       libavahi-client3                                   
> 9)       libavahi-common3                                   
> 10)      libc6                                              
> 11)      libcairo2                                          
> 12)      libcomerr2                                         
> 13)      libcups2                                           
> 14)      libcurl3                                           
> 15)      libdatrie1                                         
> 16)      libdb5.1                                           
> 17)      libdbus-1-3                                        
> 18)      libdbusmenu-qt2                                    
> 19)      libexpat1                                          
> 20)      libffi6                                            
> 21)      libflac8                                           
> 22)      libfontconfig1                                     
> 23)      libfreetype6                                       
> 24)      libgcc1                                            
> 25)      libgcrypt11                                        
> 26)      libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0                                 
> 27)      libglib2.0-0                                       
> 28)      libgnutls26                                        
> 29)      libgpg-error0                                      
> 30)      libgssapi-krb5-2                                   
> 31)      libgtk2.0-0                                        
> 32)      libice6                                            
> 33)      libidn11                                           
> 34)      libjack-jackd2-0                                   
> 35)      libjasper1                                         
> 36)      libjpeg62                                          
> 37)      libjson0                                           
> 38)      libk5crypto3                                       
> 39)      libkeyutils1                                       
> 40)      libkrb5-3                                          
> 41)      libkrb5support0                                    
> 42)      liblcms1                                           
> 43)      libldap-2.4-2                                      
> 44)      libmng1                                            
> 45)      libnspr4                                           
> 46)      libnspr4-0d                                        
> 47)      libnss3                                            
> 48)      libnss3-1d                                         
> 49)      libogg0                                            
> 50)      libpango1.0-0                                      
> 51)      libpcre3                                           
> 52)      libpixman-1-0                                      
> 53)      libpng12-0                                         
> 54)      libpulse0                                          
> 55)      libqt4-dbus                                        
> 56)      libqt4-declarative                                 
> 57)      libqt4-network                                     
> 58)      libqt4-script                                      
> 59)      libqt4-sql                                         
> 60)      libqt4-xml                                         
> 61)      libqt4-xmlpatterns                                 
> 62)      libqtcore4                                         
> 63)      libqtgui4                                          
> 64)      librtmp0                                           
> 65)      libsamplerate0                                     
> 66)      libsasl2-2                                         
> 67)      libsasl2-modules                                   
> 68)      libselinux1                                        
> 69)      libsm6                                             
> 70)      libsndfile1                                        
> 71)      libspeexdsp1                                       
> 72)      libsqlite3-0                                       
> 73)      libssl1.0.0                                        
> 74)      libstdc++6                                         
> 75)      libtasn1-3                                         
> 76)      libthai0                                           
> 77)      libtiff4                                           
> 78)      libuuid1                                           
> 79)      libvorbis0a                                        
> 80)      libvorbisenc2                                      
> 81)      libwrap0                                           
> 82)      libx11-6                                           
> 83)      libxau6                                            
> 84)      libxcb-render0                                     
> 85)      libxcb-shm0                                        
> 86)      libxcb1                                            
> 87)      libxcomposite1                                     
> 88)      libxcursor1                                        
> 89)      libxdamage1                                        
> 90)      libxdmcp6                                          
> 91)      libxext6                                           
> 92)      libxfixes3                                         
> 93)      libxft2                                            
> 94)      libxi6                                             
> 95)      libxinerama1                                       
> 96)      libxrandr2                                         
> 97)      libxrender1                                        
> 98)      libxss1                                            
> 99)      libxt6                                             
> 100)     libxv1                                             
> 101)     nspluginviewer                                     
> 102)     nspluginwrapper                                    
> 103)     skype                                              
> 104)     sni-qt                                             
> 105)     zlib1g
> ```

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is a reference for the sentence "The NTFS Write capabilities were removed in Ubuntu 11.10.", or is it only your negative experience?

Comment: It is just a reference! No negative experience at all! I am enjoying 11.10.

Comment: What's the actual reference for your claim that NTFS write support was removed? I see nothing in the release notes, and searching on Google shows nothing relevant.

Comment: NTFS write support was ***not*** removed in Ubuntu 11.10. I am running Ubuntu 11.10 right now, I have not done any customization to `ntfs-3g`'s configuration, and I can write to NTFS partitions just fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need ntfs-3g to mount ntfs devices. That said, ntfs-config is only needed to configure ntfs in fstab wich I had problems with in the last upgrade. So install the first one and edit the fstab manually. A normal line to mount a ntfs disk in the boot will look like this in `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/sda4 /media/windows ntfs-3g defaults,locale=ca_ES.UTF-8 0 0
```

Where

- sda4 is the ntfs partition (the number might change in your case),
- `/media/windows` is the directory where you want it mounted (must be created manually) and
- locale  must be your language (mine is catalan) because the system uses for reading the names of files and folders.

In your case i asume must be en_GB or en_US if you're english.

If you skip the fstab edit you can still  use the ntfs partition as a user, just mount it by clicking in nautilus. But it will be mounted as user. With the fstab it's mounted by the system itself (with read/write to all so you can store your data, of course).

Wish it helps, good luck!

Comment: Yeah Thanks, I figured out that the problem came from using sudo aptitude instead of sudo apt-get. (I guess I need to dig to see what are the real differences between the two). When I tried with sudo apt-get install ntfs-config it asked to install ntfs-3g and some python staff and everything went smoothly.

Thanks again, your answer helped ;)

Comment: There is an open bug for aptitude behaving strangely: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/aptitude/+bug/831768 - and also see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/78639/why-does-aptitude-want-to-remove-a-bunch-of-files/

Answer (score 6):

There is simple way to enable NTFS-write by default:
- first install the ntfs configs using terminal command:

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-config
```

if apt not work try using aptitude

- then you just do this command to enable ntfs-config by default

  ```
  sudo mkdir -p /etc/hal/fdi/policy
  ```

and last, try to mount the ntfs drive and paste some file to it from the ubuntu and the write function is usable now.

Comment: Thanks! Though this is not an answer to the question (Bug with APTITUDE). This is what I did at the first place, installing ntfs config and then make a directory... Then use dynamic mounting instead of static for external NTFS drives.

Answer (score 2):

It is easier just to install ntfs-3g (it will remove ntfs-progs) and you will r/w support for ntfs drives. I had the same issue and it worked for me.