# Copy-Paste Not Working

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, permissions

Using precise pangolin. I am trying to copy some folders from my portable hard drive to one of the partitions. The paste button is not working in the destination folder and whenever I am trying a drag-drop with my mouse, it says that I don't have permission to create there, albeit I have the root. Even the new folder button is not working. Help please. [Dialogue box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ur5N8.png) and [Permission details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpRBO.png) attached.

Comment: You may want to have a look at these questions: http://askubuntu.com/questions/47538/how-to-make-read-only-file-system-writable, and e.g. http://askubuntu.com/questions/77655/how-do-i-enable-ntfs-write-support (and more) in case your partition is NTFS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open a terminal (you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>) and type:

```
gksudo nautilus
```

A new Nautilus browsing window will appear. Use it to copy and paste the results.

Comment: `sudo nautilus` is [a bad idea](http://askubuntu.com/q/11760/12864), `gksu nautilus` is best.

Comment: Hi, I thought gksu is for graphical applications and since nautilus is a file manager, we can open it with sudo.

Comment: Nautilus is a graphical application. It involves the use of X, and it displays quite a few icons. Do you mind if I change it to `gksudo`?

Comment: I agree with @ObsessiveFOSS , 'gksudo' will be more appropriate.

Comment: You can try restarting nautilus http://askubuntu.com/a/489574/271328

Answer (score 1):

I think I get your problem.
Lets assume your destination folder is /home/user/MOVIES

If you are using your root account (Not recommend it) do the follwing

```
 chmod 777 /home/user/MOVIES  (You give all the permissions to your folder)
 cp /media/HARDDISK/ /home/user/MOVIES -R (You are copying all the content of your harddisk to you MOVIES folder)  
 if you have a special folder just specify it /media/HARDDISK/SPECIALFOLDER -R means recursive, you are going to copy what is on that folder)
```

If you check your destination folder only has access permissions, you can't write on it.

Answer (score 0):

Each time I want to do this I have to Open a terminal and type `gksudo nautilus` to do the paste.

(I wonder myself if there any permanent option to do copy/paste.)