# How to Link Drives of windows to Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, mount, hard-drive, ntfs

I am using DUALBOOT (Windows+Ubuntu)

I am unable to access my windows content in Ubuntu platform. When i am trying to use Ubuntu, I am getting this error

```
Error mounting /dev/sda6 at /media/satya/New Volume: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000" "/dev/sda6" "/media/satya/New Volume"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda6': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

Comment: From the message "Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting)" so .... You have to first boot windows and disable hibernation and fast boot.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you boot into Windows and then perform a full hard drive test 
(Check Disk) and let it correct any potential problems.
If your familiar with going into the bios, or utilities you may also be able to perform a HDD Smart Test.

If all these pass, Ubuntu should be able to mount those partitions by default installation. If not make sure you have ntfs-3g installed.
Read more [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/77655/how-do-i-enable-ntfs-write-support).

Comment: This answer is wrong as the problem is with windows fast boot and/or hibernation. For details see - https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation